# Converting Labels to Annotations moves position of labels

Tags: labeling, contour

Why are my contour line labels moving after I convert them to annotations?

I am using Maplex to place them. But if they still move after I converte them to annotations, the whole maplex placing process doesn't make sense.

Comment: What do you mean they're moving?

Comment: They aren't at the same place anymore. Now, I'm using Maplex just for a rought placement and do the exact placement by hand in illustrator.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question.  I am having the same issue!